# Prove that if $f: X \to Y$ is closed and continuous such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for all $y \in Y$, then $Y$ is $T_3$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a $T_3$ space, $F \subset X$ closed and $C \subset X$ compact such that $F \cap C = \emptyset$. Show that $F$ and $C$ have disjoint neighborhoods. Using this prove that if $f: X \to Y$ is closed and continuous such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for all $y \in Y$, then $Y$ is $T_3$.

Since $X$ is $T_3$ we can find open sets $c \in U_c$ and $F \subset U_F^c$ for every $c \in C$ such that $U_c \cap U_F^c = \emptyset$. Now the collection $\{U_c \mid c \in C\}$ forms a covering for $C$ and as $C$ is compact we can find a finite subcover $\{V_c \mid c \in C\} \subset \{U_c \mid c \in C\}$. Now $A = \bigcup V_c$ is an open set containing $C$ and $B= \bigcap V_F^c$ is an open set containing $F$ which are disjoint.

Let $F$ be a closed set $Y$ and $y \in F^c$, then $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact. Thus by the previous property there exists $U$ containing $f^{-1}(F)$ and $V$ containing $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ with $U \cap V = \emptyset$. How do I get from here to showing that $F$ and $y$ contain disjoint neighborhoods in $Y$?

Comment: I think the question ought to assume that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Otherwise, let $X$ be a compact metric space, let $Y$ be the cofinite topology on an infinite set, and let $f$ map every element of $X$ to a single element of $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

Finding disjoint open neighbourhoods $S$ and $T$ separating $f^{-1}(F)$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$

is the same as finding closed sets $C=S^c$ and $D=T^c$ such that

- $C\bigcup D=X$
- $C\bigcap f^{-1}(F)=\emptyset$
- $D\bigcap f^{-1}(\{y\})=\emptyset$.

Now, look at $f(C)$ and $f(D)$. In particular, observe that since $f^{-1}(F)$ contains all the points in $X$ that are mapped to $F$, we have $f(C)\bigcap F=\emptyset$.

$\\$

In general topology, it is a useful trick to ask yourself how a concept that is expressed in terms of open sets can also be expressed in terms of closed sets, and whether this change makes it easier to think about the problem at hand.